# Bitshifting a long in Java

Tags: java, bit-shift

Im sure this is an easy one for whoever sees it first!

Why in Java does code like

```
   long one = 1 << 0;
   long thirty = 1 << 30;
   long thirtyOne = 1 << 31;
   long thirtyTwo = 1 << 32;

   System.out.println(one+" = "+Long.toBinaryString(1 << 0));
   System.out.println(thirty+" = "+Long.toBinaryString(1 << 30));
   System.out.println(thirtyOne+" = "+Long.toBinaryString(1 << 31));
   System.out.println(thirtyTwo+" = "+Long.toBinaryString(1 << 32));
```

print

```
1 = 1
1073741824 = 1000000000000000000000000000000
-2147483648 = 1111111111111111111111111111111110000000000000000000000000000000
1 = 1
```

This does not make sense to me. `long` is a 64 bit number - whereas it seems to act like an `int` in the above. I know bitshifted `byte`s undergo int promotion but I dont see whats going on in this case.

Any pointers on whats going on here would be good :)

Thx

**EDIT**: thanks for all the answers - i realised what was going on as soon as I clicked 'submit' but SO went into `readonly` mode and I couldnt delete! Many thanks!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It's because 1 is an `int` literal, so `<<` is applied to an integer. The result is cast to a `long`, but by then it's too late.

If you write 1L << 32, *etc.*, then all will be well. `L` is used to denote a `long` literal.

Comment: So non-intuitive for not a Java expert.
Thanks, I had the same issue without a clue what is wrong, until I found this after long time of browsing

Answer (score 4):

First of all:

Java Language Specification [paragraph 15.19](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.19)

> Shift Operators
>
> If the promoted type of the left-hand operand is int, **only the five lowest-order bits of the right-hand operand are used** as the shift distance. It is as if the right-hand operand were subjected to a bitwise logical AND operator & (§15.22.1) with the mask value 0x1f (0b11111). The shift distance actually used is therefore always in the range 0 to 31, inclusive.
>
> If the promoted type of the left-hand operand is long, then **only the six lowest-order bits of the right-hand operand are used** as the shift distance. It is as if the right-hand operand were subjected to a bitwise logical AND operator & (§15.22.1) with the mask value 0x3f (0b111111). The shift distance actually used is therefore always in the range 0 to 63, inclusive.

So, why does it work as if you are shifting `int`s instead of `long`s? Because you are shifting `int`s! Try using a `long` literal instead:

```
long thirtyTwo = 1L << 32;
```

Answer (score 3):

Well you're using int literals, which behave like ints. Use a long literal (i.e. `1L`) instead:

```
System.out.println(1 << 31);
System.out.println(1L << 31);  // <--
```

```
-2147483648
2147483648
```

When you have an expression like `1 << 31`, it evaluates to a fixed value irrespective of what it's being assigned to, be it `int` or `long`.

Answer (score 3):

It acts like an `int` because you are shifting ints !  To shift a long, you must suffix all your number with `l`.

```
long one = 1l << 0;
long thirty = 1l << 30;
long thirtyOne = 1l << 31;
long thirtyTwo = 1l << 32;

System.out.println(one+" = "+Long.toBinaryString(1l << 0));
System.out.println(thirty+" = "+Long.toBinaryString(1l << 30));
System.out.println(thirtyOne+" = "+Long.toBinaryString(1l << 31));
System.out.println(thirtyTwo+" = "+Long.toBinaryString(1l << 32));
```

Which gives the following result :

```
1 = 1
1073741824 = 1000000000000000000000000000000
2147483648 = 10000000000000000000000000000000
4294967296 = 100000000000000000000000000000000
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because the number `1` in the line `long thirtyTwo = 1 << 32;` is an `int` by default. You need to explicit mark it as a long before you do the shift operation. What happens now is that you do a shift on an `int` which then after the shift is done is casted from an `int` to a `long`.

```
   long one = 1l << 0;
   long thirty = 1l << 30;
   long thirtyOne = 1l << 31;
   long thirtyTwo = 1l << 32;
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `1` is an integer. It will be converted to a long *after* the shift. Try

```
   long one = 1l << 0;
   long thirty = 1l << 30;
   long thirtyOne = 1l << 31;
   long thirtyTwo = 1l << 32;
```

Answer (score 1):

literal 1 is an int. Use 1L (L as long) and retry.