# Python bitshifting to java

Tags: java, python, bit-shift

I found a python code on github, and I need to do the same thing in java, I have almost converted it to java but I'm getting an warning saying `Shift operation '>>' by overly large constant value`

this is the python code that I'm trying to convert

```
if i > 32:
  return (int(((j >> 32) & ((1 << i))))) >> i
return (int((((1 << i)) & j))) >> i
```

and this is the java code I made trying to convert from the python code

```
if (i > 32) {
    return (j >> 32) & (1 << i) >> i;
  }
return ((1 << i) & j) >> i;
```

the warning is in this line `(j >> 32)`

Comment: What type is `j`?

Comment: `j` is an integer value

Comment: `byte`, `short`, `int`, or `long`? The exact type matters.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bitshifting a long in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22330107/bitshifting-a-long-in-java)

Comment: It is the same as doing `j = 0`. That's why.

Comment: Unfortunately, when porting a program to another language, you cannot assume things work the same. The bit-shift operators in Java an python behave quite differently. Don't just assume that your results will be the same!

Comment: How did you get that warning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Java's `int` is 32 bits (See [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)), shifting it 32 bits to the right leaves nothing from the original `int`, and therefore doesn't make much sense

Comment: That's interesting. It might have something to do with Java 8 allowing unsigned int (even though I still find it weird to shift the entire int out).

Comment: "Java 8 allowing unsigned int" .. what do you mean by that?

Comment: It's detailed in the link in my answer: "Static methods like compareUnsigned, divideUnsigned etc have been added to the Integer class to support the arithmetic operations for unsigned integers".

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't really make sense to me because shifting 32 bits in an int leaves nothing, How ever if you want to implant the same method using long, here is the code I wrote to do so.

```
public int bitShift(long j, int i) {
    return i > 32 ? ((int) ((j >> 32) & ((long) (1 << i)))) >> i : ((int) (j & ((long) (1 << i)))) >> i;
}
```